# How is entropy taken into account in a FV solver?

Tags: finite-volume, numerical-modelling

When solving for a given PDE, how is the entropy taken into account? Does the fluxes has another form? Or is the entropy PDE for a given entropy-flux included in the solver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that for a non-discretized hyperbolic system, the entropy condition guarantees that the unique weak solution satisfying the entropy condition is equivalent to the limit of the associated parabolic equation as viscocity goes to zero. With this in mind, one can enforce entropy conditions on a discretization by adding artificial viscocity. This has the effect of preventing expansion shocks in the numerical solution, i.e., shocks of the correct magnitude (according to Rankine-Hugoniot) but the wrong sign (violates entropy condition). One popular way to fix this for Euler/Navier-Stokes equations is to explicitly smooth the solution by filtering the eigenvalues obtained in the flux computations in a finite-volume scheme. A popular example of such a scheme is given in Harten, 1983.

*Harten, Ami*, [**High resolution schemes for hyperbolic conservation laws**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991(83)90136-5), J. Comput. Phys. 49, 357-393 (1983). [ZBL0565.65050](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0565.65050).

Comment: Let's say we want to solve Euler equations, does you answer mean that you add artificial viscosity to the entropy Euler equations? Not Euler equations itself?

Comment: IIRC not many implementations explicitly add a viscocity term to the RHS of the PDE. However, doing so would achieve the desired result, albeit at the cost of accuracy. It is more common to add viscocity via filtering the eigenvalues of the linearized flux (or Roe flux or something) in the Riemann solver. This is done in addition to any physical viscocity that may be present in the original equations. If the filtering is done correctly, then it should only impact scenarios where an expansion shock is likely and leave most other flow patterns alone.

Answer (score 2):

The are many "entropy conditions" and much literature on the topic. Quoting from memory, I recall these, which I cite informally.

A. The solution must be the limit as $\varepsilon\downarrow 0$ of a dissipative conservation law.

B. The solution with discontinuous data must be the appropriate limit of solutions with smooth data.

C. Some entropy function that is conserved in smooth flows must increase in nonsmooth flows. This may be the thermodynamic entropy $\ln{p}-\gamma\ln{\rho}$ or some function of it, such as $p/\rho^\gamma$

These consideration apply at the p.d.e level as well as at the discrete level.
Some discrete solvers are described as "entropy satisfying" in one or more of these senses. The Roe solver is not, and is usually implemented with an "entropy fix". Even this detail occupies nearly ten pages on Google Scholar. The most comprehensive answer to your question is probably found in Tadmor, E., 2016. Entropy stable schemes. In Handbook of Numerical Analysis (Vol. 17, pp. 467-493). Elsevier.